# showing pdf in browser tab through ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, pdf

I have used [**jquery.fileDownload**](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)  and Spring for downloading .pdf files through Ajax.

The application is working fine and the pdf is downloading successfully. The problem is that Instead of downloading I want the pdf to be opened within a new Browser Tab.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

### Server Side

I am using Spring at the server side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "exportPDF", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = APP_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public void getPDF(final HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "empId", required = true) final String empId) throws IOException, Exception
{
    final byte[] pdf= ExportPDFUtil.getFileBytes(empId); // get the file bytes
    final OutputStream output = getOutputStream(response);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=documents_" + new DateTime() + ".pdf");
    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    response.setContentLength(pdf.length);
    write(output, pdf);
}
```

### Client Side

At the client side, I am using AngularJS

```
$downloadXLS = function(id)
{
    $.fileDownload('/user/exportPDF', 
    {
        httpMethod : "POST",
        data : {
            empId : id
        }
    }).done(function(e, response)
    {
     // success
    }).fail(function(e, response)
    {
     // failure
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) from Mozilla.Most of the applications use this for displaying PDFs in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; 
                  filename=documents_" + new DateTime() + ".pdf");
```

instead of:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;
                  filename=documents_" + new DateTime() + ".pdf");
```